# How to route pulse audio device into alsa loopback (virtual microphone)?

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, loop-device

I want a flash application that wants to record my microphone (something like https://online-voice-recorder.com/) to record a Pulse Audio source.

I figured, that flash uses ALSA. So I installed the Alsa loop device `sudo modprobe snd-aloop`, which neatly appeared both in `pavucontrol` and in `alplay -l` (at the end of the listing):

`adam@adam-g551jm:~ 130 $ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC668 Analog [ALC668 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Loopback [Loopback], device 0: Loopback PCM [Loopback PCM]
  Subdevices: 7/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 2: Loopback [Loopback], device 1: Loopback PCM [Loopback PCM]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7`

Then I confirmed, that the sound is routed to the loopback device: 
[image: Screenshot of pavucontrol]

Unfortunately, the flash plugin doesn't see the sound at all - as if I was recording zeroes.

The flash plugin sees all ALSA-facing sound sources:

[image: Flash config]

1. Why there is no sound visible to the flash plugin?
2. What to do, to route a Pulse Audio's output into ALSA input?

Comment: How did you configure the Flash plugin?

Comment: I think it is not possible this way (using the `loopback` module). According to the [module description](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index64h3), this "allows one to route audio from a source directly back to a sink". But what you need is routing a sink or a different source to another source (microphone).

Comment: @CL I've selected the `loopback` device as a microphone, and cranked up the volume to max. See the updated question.

Comment: @ridgy. I'm not an expert, and I don't really understand what you mean. I need to plug *source* from Pulse Audio, to the `loopback` sink in ALSA.

Comment: Does `arecord` on the loopback device work?

Comment: Sorry, I was talking about the loopback module in pulseaudio. But in contrary to my previous comment, this way I managed to do what what you wanted. Is  your flash  application regarding PA, or only ALSA devices?

Comment: @ridgy Flash sees only ALSA devices.

Comment: Don't have the time to test, but maybe the following links may help: http://blog.vrplumber.com/b/2012/06/14/alsa-loopback-devices-for/ and http://blog.vrplumber.com/b/2012/06/15/alsa-loopback-for-fun/

Comment: @ridgy Either ALSA has changed the configuration format, or I failed to understand the author's markup. Pasting the quoted configuration into `.asoundrc` gives a syntax error and no sound at all on the whole machine after reboot. This guide is too difficult for me...

Comment: I got the loopback device to work the way you did, and could record with `arecord -D hw:CARD=Loopback,DEV=1 -f cd -V stereo | aplay`, but not with `DEV=0`.  But the flash didn't work either, as there is no selection of the device. Maybe someone could help how to route the sound to `DEV=0`?

Comment: @ridgy Flash does give me the option to change to different ALSA device. What *exactly* did you do? Did you touch the `.asoundrc`? Did you use `modprobe snd-aloop`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simple answer is at the end. But to help understand the solution, I will try to be as intelligible as possible. My assumption: "Loopback device" is card #2, device #0 and #1, so in all examples this holds true (e.g. `/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p`means "card 2, device 0, playback"). Your installation may vary, so modify the respective values.

First, I created/modified `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-aloop.conf` to have only one card with only one substream (just for simplicity):

```
user@desk:~$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-aloop.conf 
options snd-aloop index=2 pcm_substreams=1 id=Loopback
```

After `sudo modprobe snd_aloop`, `aplay -l` and `arecord -l` show

```
user@desk:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
.
.
card 2: Loopback [Loopback], device 0: Loopback PCM [Loopback PCM]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Loopback [Loopback], device 1: Loopback PCM [Loopback PCM]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

user@desk:~$ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 2: Loopback [Loopback], device 0: Loopback PCM [Loopback PCM]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Loopback [Loopback], device 1: Loopback PCM [Loopback PCM]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Now, there is one problem: Both devices of the loopback card are playback as well as record devices. But the function of `snd_aloop` is to route input in device 0 to output at device 1 and vice versa (see e.g.https://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix:Module-aloop). You can see these in `/proc/asound`directory:

```
user@desk:~$ ls /proc/asound/card2
cable#0  cable#1  id  pcm0c  pcm0p  pcm1c  pcm1p
```

where "pcm0c" is capture device 0, "pcm0p" is playback device 0 etc.

So `pavucontrol` shows (and selects) two loop devices, one playback (hw:2,0) and one record (hw:2,1):

[image]
[image]

You cannot select the playback device in `pavucontrol`, so it selects device 0:

[image]

You will see this when loking at the playback device file:

```
user@desk:~$ lsof | grep /dev/snd/pcmC2
pulseaudi 3314               user  mem       CHR             116,13                 556 /dev/snd/pcmC2D0p
pulseaudi 3314               user   48u      CHR             116,13      0t0        556 /dev/snd/pcmC2D0p
alsa-sink 3314 3320          user  mem       CHR             116,13                 556 /dev/snd/pcmC2D0p
alsa-sink 3314 3320          user   48u      CHR             116,13      0t0        556 /dev/snd/pcmC2D0p
.
.
```

So this means the capturing of this audio stream has to be done via `/dev/snd/pcmC2D1c`; if you select `loopback`as the input device for flash, it will use `/dev/snd/pcmC2D0c`instead (`plugin-co`means the plugin container flash is running in):

```
user@desk:~$ lsof | grep /dev/snd/pcmC2
pulseaudi 3314               user  mem       CHR             116,13                 556 /dev/snd/pcmC2D0p
pulseaudi 3314               user   48u      CHR             116,13      0t0        556 /dev/snd/pcmC2D0p
.
.
plugin-co 5093               user  mem       CHR             116,14                 557 /dev/snd/pcmC2D0c
plugin-co 5093               user   21u      CHR             116,14      0t0        557 /dev/snd/pcmC2D0c
.
.
```

You may check when explicitly playing sound through `/dev/snd/pcmC2D1p`, e.g. with

```
user@desk:~$ aplay -D hw:2,1 test1.wav
Playing WAVE 'test1.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 44100 Hz, Mono
```

Now the flash plugin records sound, and you can see the difference:

```
user@desk:~$ lsof | grep pcmC2
.
.
aplay     7256               user  mem       CHR             116,15                  558 /dev/snd/pcmC2D1p
aplay     7256               user    4u      CHR             116,15       0t0        558 /dev/snd/pcmC2D1p
.
.
plugin-co 7237               user  mem       CHR             116,14                  557 /dev/snd/pcmC2D0c
plugin-co 7237               user   21u      CHR             116,14       0t0        557 /dev/snd/pcmC2D0c
.
.
```

So, the task now is: **How to have pulseaudio select the device #1 of the loopback card for playback?**

Assuming the values from above, you may modify `/etc/pulse/default.pa` to read

```
.
.
### Load audio drivers statically
### (it's probably better to not load these drivers manually, but instead
### use module-udev-detect -- see below -- for doing this automatically)
#load-module module-alsa-sink
#load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:1,0
.
.
load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:2,1
.
.
```

Be sure to define the statically driver(s) *before* the dynamic ones. 
Now after restart of PA (`pulseaudio -k`), the `loopback` output of PA goes to card2, device 1 (`device=hw:2,1`). To verify:

```
user@desk:~$ lsof | grep pcmC2
pulseaudi 8584               user  mem       CHR             116,15                  558 /dev/snd/pcmC2D1p
pulseaudi 8584               user   18u      CHR             116,15       0t0        558 /dev/snd/pcmC2D1p
alsa-sink 8584 8585          user  mem       CHR             116,15                  558 /dev/snd/pcmC2D1p
alsa-sink 8584 8585          user   18u      CHR             116,15       0t0        558 /dev/snd/pcmC2D1p
.
.
```

Thus, your flash recorder is able to record from the output of pulseaudio.

Remark: If you do not want to edit `/etc/pulse/default.pa`, you can load the module interactively with `pacmd load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:2,1`. This will give you a second `loopback`device in `pavucontrol`. And if you only want one loopback device, first unload the respective module:

```
user@desk:~$ pacmd list-modules
.
.
    index: 7
    name: <module-alsa-card>
    argument: <device_id="2" name="platform-snd_aloop.0" card_name="alsa_card.platform-snd_aloop.0" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1">
    used: 0
    load once: no
    properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "ALSA Card"
        module.version = "8.0"
```

Look for the index where `device-id=2` (here:7), then unload the module (`pacmd unload-module 7`) and after that load the sink for the loopback (`pacmd load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:2,1`).

Comment: For me the solution was this (for some reason PA uses wrong sink by default):
`pulseaudio -k && pactl load-module module-alsa-sink`