# How to set a loopback as default audio input device?

Tags: 18.04, sound, alsa, microphone, input-devices

I'm using [WO Mic for Linux](https://wolicheng.com/womic/wo_mic_linux.html) and I would like to config my phone's mic to work on my PC. WO Mic is an app that sends your phone's audio input over WiFi to the local server on your PC. I start the app with:

```
$ ./micclient-x86_64.AppImage -t Wifi [IP HERE]
```

and to test it I used the snippet from their website:

```
$ arecord -c 1 -r 48000 -f S16_LE -D "hw:CARD=Loopback,DEV=1,SUBDEV=0" foo.wav
```

The audio was muffled, which is not great, but the real problem I have is that I cannot use this is because **it doesn't show up in settings as an input device**. I've Googled around a bit, but nobody seems to be using the app on Linux so I found nothing. How to configure this so I can use it in Discord and such?

Comment: Did you follow all the instructions on their page?

Comment: Are you using Pulseaudio? I have just tried using WO Mic on Linux and experienced the symptoms you describe, that were caused by Pulseaudio not using the WO Mic ALSA loopback device properly, like in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/895216/how-to-route-pulse-audio-device-into-alsa-loopback-virtual-microphone). Basically, I solved my problems adding this line to `/etc/pulse/default.pa`: `load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:2,1 source_properties=device.description="WO\ Mic"`

Comment: @AlejandroGonzález I really thank you, I added that line in default.pa file and solved